# EXCEL call sql server stored procedure => columns problem

Tags: sql-server, excel

A sql stored procedure with 2 parameters (project & version) is called in excel:

`DRIVER=SQL Server Native Client 11.0;SERVER=xxx;UID=;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=Microsoft Office;WSID=xxx;DATABASE=xxx;`

`EXECUTE [DW].[ExportProjectReport] ?,?;`

The stored procedure is dynamical and returns different time ranges as columns (months) per project:

`SET @cols = STUFF((`
`SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(LEFT([Date],7)) + ' FLOAT'` 
`FROM [planning_table]`
`WHERE LEFT([Date],7) >= @mindate AND LEFT([Date],7) <= @maxdate`
`order by 1 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')`

`DECLARE @tempTable TABLE (`
       `[Project Key] VARCHAR(50)`
       `...`
      `,' + @cols + '`
`); ...`

Problem: When changing the project parameter in xls, which should return different time range per project (months as columns), the order of columns is faulty. It keeps the months from the first query (project) and adds previous months of a new project at the end. When changing the project parameter multiple times, even the names of the colums (months) are getting faulty:  e.g  2017-55 (instead of 2017-12)
Options like disabling "Keep layout for colums" do not solve this issue.
It seems that the return result from the first call is saved, and further calls with different result set (colums) can't be handled correctly.

How to solve this, or do I have to adopt the stored procedure to deliever static results (always same # of columns).

Comment: Instead of using that stored procedure let *Excel* itself pivot the data. An Excel Pivot table is a far better UI and far simpler to use than a dynamic PIVOT statement. The hand-coded pivoting and aggregation prevents you from using Excel's date filtering and aggregation functionality too

Answer (score 0):

Yes if it would be one table I would use SSAS Cube with Power Pivot in XLS
But, I have 5 sheets with raw data (5 different stored procedure calls) per project, which should be put together to one report per VBA, including special layout und various calculations...
Therefore I'm doing the pivot for all 5 sources in SQL to ensure that the number of colums und rows is the same over all projects for all 5 sources

BR wopro